# Size of an atom

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, estimation, history

This may be a naive question, but today, while reading about the Rutherford experiment in my high school chemistry textbook, I came across the following sentence:

> "Calculations by Rutherford showed that  the volume occupied by the nucleus is negligibly small as compared to the total volume of the atom.The radius of the atom is about $1$ angstrom, while that of the nucleus is $1$ femtometer."

My question is since we know the atomic radii of different elements are distinct, so for what atom did Rutherford calculate the atomic radius for?

Comment: Rutherford's original experiment of 1911 was scattering alpha particles on gold, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_model and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering

Comment: The key point of the statement is that **it does not really matter**, which atom we use, because the size of the atom is order of magnitudes larger than the size of the nucleus. We still talk about Rutherford, because he proofed that the size of the nucleus is **small** compared to the size of the atom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Rutherford experiment, from which he derived that statement you mentioned, he was shooting $\alpha$-particles (Helium cores) at gold foil.

However you should note that neither atoms nor nuclei are solid spheres and are instead described by a quantum mechanical wave function. Even if one does neglect the QM-nature, which is probably not too unreasonable for particles heavier then protons at usual conditions on Earth, the scattering should still at least be modeled as a Coulomb interaction and its [cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)) therefore depends on more then just the involved particle species, e.g., also the kinetic energy of the particles will play a role.

Answer (score 0):

> *«for what atom did Rutherford calculate the atomic radius for?*»

Rutherford's model of the atom for this experiment consisted of a positive charge (of unknown composition and distribution over an atom-sized region) surrounded by a compensating cloud of electrons (about a hundred for a gold atom). These electrons could not deflect the alpha particles incident in the experiment, since they are a thousand times lighter. Therefore, only positive charge (somehow distributed in an unknown way in the atom) should have participated in the scattering of alpha particles. The measured angular distribution of deflected alpha particles turned out to be **as if all this positive charge was concentrated at one point** (taking into account the measurement error), and was not at all spread out over an atomic-sized area.

Comment: Gold doesn't have more electrons than uranium. ;) And the alpha particle mass is ~7200× the electron mass.